# CSS not rendering in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, css

I have created a CEWP in which I have been displaying custom page. I have created a library within which I have stored all my text, css, js, img (separate folder). To call all these files, I have given a relative path to this library. While text, js, images are loading well in Chrome and IE, CSS is not rendering in Chrome (Working fine in IE). The page is not throwing any error though. What could be the reason for this? How to I make my CSS render?

This is how I am calling my CSS from HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/PLM/style.css">
```

where PLM is the name of my library.

Comment: While all the files are loading well in Chrome and IE, CSS is not rendering in Chrome?????????

Comment: @AtishDipongkor i mean except CSS all other files are running fine on Chrome and IE.... While, CSS is working fine on IE but not at all rendering on Chrome. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: check in my edited code

Comment: It seems ok. are you getting any console error?

Comment: This is the only error that i am getting, which I feel won't affect how CSS renders on a page: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentElement' of null

Comment: after page loading... go the source tab and see your css file is there or not. I think css is loading completely. problem is in other place

Comment: I can't see any CSS in Source Tab

Comment: in source tab ..... press Ctrl+O and type style.css

Comment: wrote. Now what? There wasn't any file named style.css in the drop-down in Source Tab

Comment: Is it there? I mean did you find the style.css file there?

Comment: Nope... I can't find any file named style.css

Comment: That means your href is not valid. Check it again

Comment: If the syntax and format is correct then the path is also correct. I tried this as well: "<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mvms172:9999/PLM/style.css"> This path i found by opening my CSS in new tab and Copy+Paste in href

Comment: Check the path/reference by opening the css file directly as page/URI in Chrome.

Comment: that what i did. check my previous comment... what you are looking in href is what the absolute path to style.css is. Funny part is that with the same reference, I am able to load images

Comment: yap ...... it seems all right. Try my last solution: clear you browser history and try again. @DannyEngelman said that hit this URL http://mvms172:9999/PLM/style.css in Chrome and let us know

Comment: When you say " in which I have been displaying custom page"; are you mixing domain names?  Chrome is really tight on security: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060786/file-url-cross-domain-issue-in-chrome-unexpected

Comment: Thank you all for your responses... There was some error on my side.. I was checking an incorrect link.. I am deleting this question